# map function doesn't return length of array's words

Tags: javascript

[Beginner's task], I have a String which I turned into an array via `split()`, I then learned of the `map(function(x))` which supposedly returns another array via a function.

The objective is to determine and `return` the longest word of an array as a number, but when running my code I only get the numbers of all words. I am aware that something is missing to complete the task, but I'd like to know
a) Why does `map`'s function take an argument (x) and that argument represents each of the words in the original array? And b) what am i missing to complete the task? I am unsure what algorithm would arrange for only the largest # to show up. Thank you in advance and sorry for the poor explanation.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var array = str.split(' ');
  var lengths = array.map(function(x){
    return x.length;
  });
  return lengths;
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: you can sort the length array and get the longest

Comment: I'm about to leave my computer, but you shouldn't really use `.map` for this, as you only want one result, use `.reduce`

Comment: API documentations exist for a reason

Comment: I will look into `.reduce' and get back to the post later after reading up about it. Thank you
Can you explain my question tagged as `a)` ??

Comment: `arr.reduce((a,b) => a.length > b.length ? a: b)`

Comment: I found a solution via a combination of things, please see below

Answer (score 2):

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns the result of applying the specified function to each element in a list as another list. In your case, you are getting the length of each element in the list, so applying map you will get:

```
[3, 5, 5, 3, 6, 4, 3, 4, 3]
```

If you want to get the longest number, you just have to iterate over it and select it

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to the `.map()` method is automatically passed 3 arguments by the JavaScript runtime (you don't need to do anything to make that happen):

- a reference to the array item being enumerated
- the index of the array item being enumerated
- a reference to the array being enumerated

As with all JavaScript arguments, you can choose to explicitly receive some, none or all of them, simply by setting up named arguments in the callback function (you may call the arguments any valid identifier name you like).

Now, for your task, **[`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** really isn't the best choice, **[`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** is (since it returns just a single value), but you could get `.map()` to work, you'll just have to **[get the highest number out of the resulting array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)**:

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var array = str.split(' ');
  // The callback function will automatically be passed 3 parameters.
  // Use them or not depending on what you are doing in the callback.
  var lengths = array.map(function(item, index, arry){
    console.log(item, index, arry);  // Just for demonstration
    return item.length; // Put the current array item into the resulting array
  });
  return lengths;  // Return the resulting array to the caller
}

// You'll need to call the Math.max() method and pass 
// it the array to get the highest number in the array
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")));
```

To do this using the `.reduce()` method:

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  // Take the string and split into an array of words that then
  // has the replace() method applied to those words:
  return str.split(' ').reduce(function(a, b) {
    // We want the length of the longer word returned
    // but, after the first iteration, the parameter "a"
    // won't be a word, it will be the number returned 
    // from the last iteration, so we need to do Math.max
    // against either the word's length (first iteration)
    // or the value of a returned from the prior iteration
    // on the second and subsequent iterations a.length will
    // be undefined so just a will be used.
    return Math.max(a.length || a, b.length);
  });
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: Please see my answer below

Comment: I find your solution so damn simple it hurts to not have been able to get to it myself. Can you explain by chance what the `a, b` argument does in your callback ?

If I understand correct, `a, b` could be `y, u`, or any other letters for that matter. The point is that two arguments are passed through, in the form of numbers from the array, and that the `Math.max()` function then determines the length of `a` OR `a, b`, but why is the second argument `a, b` ? What does it do ?

Comment: @Helle `a` is the "accumulator - - the previous value returned from the last invocation of the callback function. But, in the first iteration, it is the value of the first element in the array - `"The"` in this scenario. `b` is the value of the current item being iterated. So, on the first iteration `a` and `b` are actually the same thing `"The"`. The first iteration will return the `length` of `"The"` (3) and that's what `a` will be on the second iteration. Since the number `3` doesn't have a `length` property, just `3` is used (that's what `a.length || a` ensures) and then...

Comment: @Helle ...the greater number of 3 or the length of the next word `quick` is returned. So, `5` is returned and `5` is the value of `a` on the next iteration.  See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for more on `reduce()`

Comment: @Helle And, yes, you could call the arguments anything you like (`x`, `y`). They are just the names you want to use for the data being passed in automatically by the JavaScript runtime to the callback function. And to be clear, the Math.max gets `a.length` if there is one or just `a` if not AND then it always gets `b.length`.

Answer (score 0):

### Where `.map()` gets its arguments

> a) Why does map's function take an argument (x) and that argument represents each of the words in the original array?

That's how the implementation of `.map()` works. It iterates all the members of the array and invokes the callback once per iteration, passing in the current array member, and receiving back whatever you returned, which it places into the new array being built.

---

### Completing the task using `.reduce()` and `Math.max()`

> b) what am i missing to complete the task? I am unsure what algorithm would arrange for only the largest # to show up.

I wouldn't use `.map()` for this. You can use `.reduce()` instead.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  return str.split(' ').reduce((mx, word) => Math.max(mx, word.length), 0);
}

var result = findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(result);
```

The `.reduce()` method works differently. Each call to the callback has the return result of the previous iteration (`mx`) and the current word (`word`). The `0` value was provided as a starting value, so that's the value of `mx` on the first iteration. Then each iteration compares the previous value to the `.length` of the current word using `Math.max()`, which returns the greater, making it the value of `mx` on the next iteration.

At the end, the value returned on the last iteration becomes the final result.

---

### Using your array from `.map()` with `Math.max()` and "spread syntax"

However, if you were to use the array you created from `.map()`, then you could also pass its content to `Math.max()` using spread syntax.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var array = str.split(' ');
  var lengths = array.map(function(x) {
    return x.length;
  });
  return Math.max(...lengths);;
}

var result = findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(result);
```

This passes all the members of `lengths` to `Math.max` as individual arguments, and returns the largest.

---

### Making it more terse

The last solution built on your existing code, but it can be shortened a bit by avoiding the variable assignments and using an arrow function.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  return Math.max(...str.split(' ').map(x => x.length));
}

var result = findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` this way, as you need only one output

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var array = str.split(' ');
  return array.reduce(function(memo, x){
    return memo > x.length ? memo : x.length;
  }, -1);
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and in my opinion most correct way to do this, would be to split sentences on word boundaries, and then map the length and simply use `Math.max` to return the largest number

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, str.split(/\b/).map( x=>x.length) );
}

console.log( findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog") )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already returning an array of lengths of all the words after split. All you need to do is find the maximum.
Adding one line to your code makes it work:

```
    function findLongestWord(str) {
       var array = str.split(' ');
       var lengths = array.map(function(x){
           return x.length;
       });
       //---------------------------------------------
       return Math.max.apply( Math, lengths ); 
       //This is what you're missing to complete your task
    }
    var result = findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
    console.log(result);
    typeof result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting could also be used:

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
    var array = str.split(' ');
    var res = array.map(function (x, i) {
        return {length: x.length, pos: i};
    }).sort(function (a1, a2) {
        return a2.length - a1.length
    })[0];
    return array[res.pos];
}
```

Interesting if you also want to find the minimum at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I made it work with the following:

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var arrr = str.split(' ');
  var lengths = arrr.map(function(individualarrayword){
    return individualarrayword.length;
  });
  return lengths.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  });
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

I am aware this is not the cleanest, or more terse, but I am not advanced or knowledgeable to use arrow functions. Thanks or all the help. Please feel free to answer how I can shorten this particular solution, so that I can work through it. Cheers!